# Update array of progressbar in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have an `asynctask` in which I pass an array of `progressbars` as a parameter. In the `doinbackground` method, I compute the progress of each progressbar and make a call to `PublishProgress` with progress as parameter. This is how I have done:

```
static volatile int currentProgressBarIndex;

@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // display the images in now playing
        while (ScheduleManager.isScheduleRunning) {
            Iterator iterator = nowPlayingMediaSet.entrySet().iterator();
            // set images on now playing
            for (int i = 0; i < btnImgNowPlaying.length && iterator.hasNext(); ++i) {
                Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                Show mShowNowPlaying = (Show) mEntry.getKey();
                // get show status
                currentProgressBarIndex = i;
                mProgressStatus[i] = ScheduleManager
                        .getCurrentPlayingShowStatus(mShowNowPlaying);
                // Update the progress bar
                publishProgress(mProgressStatus[i]);
            }
            // sleep 20 second to show the progress
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.progBar[currentProgressBarIndex].setProgress(progress[0]);
    }
```

What happens is that, only my last `progressbar` in the array is updated. Rest are updated, but later on.. I am sure I am doing something wrong here..

Comment: Why currentProgressBarIndex? Just generate a list of your progresses and pass it to publishProgress. In onProgressUpdate iterate over the list and assign the int value to the corresponding progress bar. No need for currentProgressBarIndex.

Comment: Wow.. that was simple! It is working fine now..